# Locale in Facebook request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Anyone know why we can't see the attribute 'locale' for a user anymore? Example: the request `<app_user_id>` to Graph FB API doesn't return 'locale', just "id", "first_name", "last_name", "link", "name", "updated_time".

I searched in Graph 2.2 changelog and doesn't found anything about it, although i suspect it was a restriction made by Facebook, i don't have any proof of that.

Thanks,

Comment: Try request it using the `fields` parameter – `/{user-id}?fields=locale,…`

Comment: CBroe, i tried this request, but it just returns the id

Comment: It should work when you use a user's access token to get `locale` of that user. Otherwise, it could be a bug.